# Removing duplicates in Excel based on Priority

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to remove duplicates but based on priority. Picture below to explain better.

Example 1: highlighted in yellow. It should compare the numbers in "contact info" (find the duplicates) then compare the options in "disposition" column, prioritize it based on "Priority list" and remove the duplicate with lower priority. If disposition is the same for the duplicates then it should keep the option with later date.

Example 2: highlighted in green, it should do the same thing as example 1 but this time it should remove 'Accept Offer' since 'Declined Offer' was on later date (2022-06-16) and Accept Offer was on 2022-05-31

Example 3: highlighted in blue, it should do the same thing as example 1-2 but since disposition is the same for both, it should keep the duplicate with later date.

Is there any way to do all that at once?

[image: Question link]

Comment: Do a custom sort on disposition and sort the date descending then use Remove Duplicates on the data tab using the info column for duplicates.

Comment: Custom disposition sort is a good idea but when I sort the date in descending order, it resets the disposition column

Comment: You have to do both at the same time.  do the sort in the data tab.  Give priority to the disposition sort.